# How to judge a rectangle's relative position on Plane Coordinate System?

Tags: python, rect

for example:

```
rectangle format: rect(startX,startY, width, hight)
rect0(1,1,1,1) is above on rect1(5,5,1,1)
```

How to judge zhe relative position?

I found pygame.Rect, but not usefull for me,

Are there some others libraries by python?

---

add same necessary infomation.

zhe using case is:

I have a image, there are many icons on it can be touch,

user can also use key to control icon,

so i need  know the key user send, and response the key's function,

support keys: up down left right ok turn_left turn_right,

and every icon should support those keys

if do this things manually, it's very boring,

so i want to judge the icons relative position by python,

and exort zhe relationshop to my program.

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: You can compare the maximum y value of one rect to minimum y value of another to determine if it is above the other, and so one for the other three directions. You don't need a library to do this for you, or if you really one, write it fairly easily.

Comment: sorry, i've not descript completely, I add same necessary infomation,thank you for your advise